# Sorting issue iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsdate, sorting

Having some problem, I got it sorted but looks likes this,

```
"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM"
```

the format is "MM/dd/yyyy", I want to sort this based on day, then month, then year then time. How can I implement that?

Here is the code

```
NSSortDescriptor* nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
NSMutableArray *temp = [dateStart mutableCopy];
[temp sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSorter]];
dateStart = temp;
NSLog(@"Sorted: %@",dateStart);
```

Comment: What about showing us a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: the code is added now. thank you.

Comment: This is a very strange sort order. What's the goal?

Comment: I have the above values in an array, and i need to sort that with respect to the date value. And I used the above code. It is working, but i got the sorted output as above, that is not what i want. so any solution? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to convert the string into `NSDate` and Comparator to compare them,

```
NSArray *datesArray = @[@"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                   @"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM"];

NSLog(@"dates:%@", datesArray);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

NSArray *sortedDatesArray = [datesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];

}];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedDatesArray);
```

### Output:

```
"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM"
```